# CSS, someClass:not(.foo):not(.bar)

Tags: css

In CSS I have to specify a specific class (e.g., `.myClass`) but exclude instances that have either one of two classes (e.g., not `.foo` nor `.bar`).

I looked into CSS3 new `:not()` syntax, but I am not sure how to specify the *two* classes that I don't want to use. I believe this is incorrect (it did not work for me). However, it seems like a concise way to show what I am trying to do:

```
.myClass:not(.foo):not(.bar) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate them with a comma:

```
.myClass:not(.foo, .bar){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma in-between them:

```
.myClass:not(.foo, .bar) {
    ...
}
```

Source: http://devsnippets.com/article/5-advanced-css-pseudo-class.html